# Convert image URI into File object

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am developing an app in which my requirement to select an image from the SD card and send in to IBM Waston Visual Recognition service to identify the content in the image. I am doing like this..

```
...
private VisualRecognition service;
private VisualClassification result;
...

private void openImageFromSDCard(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
}

private void callIBMWatsonVisualRecognition(){

    try {
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(image);
        File file = new File("Image.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int c;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            fr.write(c);
        }
        result = service.classify(file).execute();
        tvResult.setText(result.toString());
        is.close();
        fr.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("THINK", "Error = " + e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

            image = data.getData();
            tvResult.setText(image.toString());
            imageSelectFlag = true;

        }
    }
}
...
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image cannot be null or not be found
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.Validator.isTrue(Validator.java:38)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v2_beta.VisualRecognition.classify(VisualRecognition.java:152)
        at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v2_beta.VisualRecognition.classify(VisualRecognition.java:124)
        at com.algor7.watsonvisiondemo.MainActivity.callIBMWatsonVisualRecognition(MainActivity.java:75)
        at com.algor7.watsonvisiondemo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please check VisualRecognition and VisualClassification classes(v2) [here](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-sdk/docs/java-sdk-2.9.0/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File(image.toString());
```

That is not how you [consume content identified by a `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). Either:

- Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, then pass the `InputStream` into your library, or
- Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, then use Java I/O to copy that `InputStream` to some file that you control, then pass that `File` into your library

Comment: try {
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(image);
            File file = new File("Image.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                fr.write(c);
            }
            result = service.classify(file).execute();
            tvResult.setText(result.toString());
            is.close();
            fr.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("THINK", "Error = " + e);
        }

Comment: But getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Image.jpg: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)". Definitely i am doing something wrong.. Please correct  me.

Comment: @Algor7: That is not how you work with files on Android. You need to use a `File` object rooted in some specific directory (e.g., `getFilesDir()` called on a `Context`, like your `Activity`). So, replace `new File("Image.jpg")` with something like `new File(getFilesDir(), "Image.jpg")`.

Comment: Please check the updated callIBMWatsonVisualRecognition() method on the post above.